# How to escape special characters in the regex ***(.*)

Tags: java, regex, escaping

I am new to Java. Can somebody help me?

Is there any method available in Java which escapes the special characters in the below regex automatically?

Before escaping **`***(.*)`** and after escaping **`\\*\\*\\*(.*)`**

I don't want to escape (.*) here.

Comment: How should the "escaper" know which asterisk you want escaped and which one you don't want escaped? Can you formulate a rule for that?

Comment: @TimPietzcker.  I got a clue after seeing your comment. I can ad an indicator before each special character that needs to be escaped.

Comment: If you can add an indicator, why not add the backslashes there?

Comment: @TimPietzcker  Yes, it makes sense. Instead of adding a different indicator, I can directly add the backslash. All such regex will come from UI, so I need to check if my UI safely allows me to pass the backslash to my Java webservice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the face of it, `Pattern.quote` appears to do the job.

However, looking at the detail of your question, it appears that you want / expect to be able to escape some meta-characters and not others.  `Pattern.quote` won't do that if you apply it to a single string.  Rather, it will quote each and every character.  (For the record, it doesn't use backslashes.  It uses "\E" and "\Q".\ which neatly avoids the cost of parsing the string to find characters that need escaping.)

But the real problem is that you haven't said how the quoter should decide which meta-characters to escape and which ones to leave intact.  For instance, how does it know to escape the first three '*' characters, but not the ".*"?

Without a clearer specification, your question is pretty much unanswerable.  And even with a specification, there is little chance of finding an easy way to do this.

IMO, a better approach would be to do the escaping before you assemble the pattern from its component parts ... assuming that's what is going on here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Stephen. I have to somehow convince my customer now :((

Comment: @JQone - how about asking the customer to specify the rules to distinguish the special characters to escape from the special characters not to escape.  If they can't tell you, you can say that you can't implement it.  (Which is true.)