# How to create a raw regexp in scala?

Tags: regex, scala, escaping

Let's say I have a string having any characters, but I don't know it until run time.

```
val s: String = "/+*à&ç"
```

How can I convert this string to a regular expression so that all special characters are escaped?

For now, trying this fails:

```
s.r.findFirstIn("What the /+*à&ç is this PatternSyntaxException?")
```

with the error:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 2
```

instead of returning the match.

Comment: How about the approach suggested by [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8573764/1497596)? That is `Pattern.quote` or `\Q` and `\E`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a scala-type method for that, but the following java does the trick.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern
Pattern.quote(s).r.findFirstIn("What the /+*à&ç is this PatternSyntaxException?")
```

returns

```
res1: Option[String] = Some(/+*à&ç)
```

Comment: `StringLike` has `replaceAllLiterally` that quotes. Interesting to wonder what method to add for your use case. `s.q`?  `s.r.quoted`?  Clearly not `s.findFirstInLiterally` etc!

Comment: For me, I needed to find all places at which the substring occurred. So if there was something like s.rquote, that would be useful.